# Root password MySQL changes random to random password macOS Sierra

Tags: mysql, terminal, root, macos-sierra

I am having a problem with MySQL. I have removed MySQL from my Mac several times but this problem is still coming back. Every 3 days I am forced to change my root password in the terminal via `skip-grant-tables --`. It is frustrating and sometimes I can't even connect when using the command `skip-grant-tables`. Whenever that happens, I am forced to reboot my Mac and hope that I can connect to MySQL on the next boot attempt. Is someone having the same problem as I am? Or does anyone have a solution for this problem. By the way, I am running MySQL 5.17.7. It is the most recent version on the MySQL website.

It is very tedious to have to reinstall MySQL every time.

Thanks in advance!

Carsten Flokstra

Comment: **ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' PASSWORD EXPIRE NEVER;** see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-expiration-policy.html

Comment: Doesn't work. I can only start my MySQL server right now in skip-grant-tables. I don't have permission to Alter the User table.

Comment: Connect to MySQL with normal cli MySQL client : **Mysql -u root -p -h localhost**

Comment: can't because the password changed

Comment: Could you try `sudo mysql` ?